# ng-repeat not tracking old key-pair value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've json like this..

```
var storedData = {  
 "Feb 7, 2017":[  
   {  
     "emMessageId":1019,
     "message":"HI",
     "userId":100166,
     "imHashTagId":null,
     "taggedUser":null,
     "iconPath":"i",
     "sendMsgDate":1486469494000
   },
   {....}
 ],
"Feb 8, 2017":[  
  {  
     "emMessageId":1090,
     "message":"hi",
     "userId":100165,
     "imHashTagId":null,
     "taggedUser":null,
     "iconPath":"i",
     "sendMsgDate":1486495671000
  },
  {....}
 ]
}
```

now i'm adding more data to "today" key like..

```
 if(!storedData['Today'])
   storedData['Today'] = [{new obj}]
 else
    storedData['Today'].push({new obj});
```

It's adding fine but "ng-repeat" not tracking old key-pairs value.Please help me Expert's, Thanks in advance.

Plunker Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/YHQhC0Qibbrr5fD73fGr?p=info

Comment: is it using scope or not

Comment: it's with controller alias name,just see the above link.

Comment: i tried adding `{{mainCtrl.storedData.Today}}` in view it showing object is seems added

Comment: adding perfect but not updating previous message time. it will show 0s on every new message it should be update with some sec.or if ng-repeat rendering old values as well then why not ng-init calling for every rendered object. just send 2 or 3 message and see the time difference not updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that `ng-repeat`, when adding a new item to `self.storedData['Today']`, is processing just that last added item.

Here is the plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/OQ9DnZBszvdrPwW1bQ0S?p=preview) that does what you want. Basically I have added a temporary array `self.todayItems` and when Send button is clicked, just do `self.storedData['Today'] = angular.copy(self.todayItems);`, which creates a copy of the entire array. Since a new array is added, all items in that array are re-evaluated.

Comment: Thank's to correct me & giving quick response, i think it was the call by reference problem.